# spreading dir output horizontally in windows 10

Tags: windows, directory, windows-10

I use dir command to find directories and files I use it in following way

```
dir /b
```

the output is following

```
biblio.bib
tg.cls
itglogo-eps-converted-to.pdf
itglogo.eps
logo-eps-converted-to.pdf
README.md
STYLES
texfiles
thesis.aux
thesis.idx
thesis.lof
thesis.log
thesis.lot
thesis.out
thesis.pdf
thesis.synctex.gz
thesis.tex
thesis.toc
```

if you see in above output just by looking at text we can not know which is directory.
I want to know how can I do some thing like in output I am able to differentiate directories from files in dir output also I want the output to come spread horizontally not vertically in windows cmd I have to scroll a lot so how can I do it?

I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `dir /W` should be enough

On my Windows 10, I see:

```
 Directory of D:\git\thermsolver

[.]                [..]               .gitattributes     .gitignore         go.mod             go.sum             [grid]             grid-schema.json
grid.yaml          main.go            thermsolver.exe
```

You can see subfolders surrounded with square brackets; eg: `[grid]`

Comment: This is really great I wonder why I could not discover it till now myself.